# Split array at index in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: arrays, oop, split, smalltalk, pharo

I'm having trouble with this:

```
Split: lista

li := Array new: 30.
aux := Array new: 30.
j := 0.
1 to: (lista size / 30) ceiling do: [ :i | 
    1 to: 30 do: [ :k | aux at: k put: (lista at: k + j) ].
    j := j + 30.
    li at: i put: aux ].
^ li
```

This is supossed to return the same list, but splitted in 30 groups of 30. I don't know what is failing, I've tried debugging it a lot of times, but it just doesn't work. At first I tried to split it at an index, but it's too hard.

Please, help me! :(

Comment: What exactly is "failing"? Please provide the error message and the first couple of method selectors from the top of the error stack.

Comment: Why 30 groups of 30? This implicit knowledge of `lista size` is fragile. The protection `(lista size / 30) ceiling`  is not going to protect from all possible edge case, notably the last chunk might be of size < 30, and there could also be more than 30 chunks...

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw: the Array `aux` containing a chunk is the same object for each chunk, overwritten at each external loop, so you'll end up with a list of 30 identical chunks.

Comment: It would be great if you could add an example of the input data and the desired output data (on a smaller array) e.g. for input array `#(1 2 3 4)` and index `2` I expect output `#(#(1 2) #(1 2) #(1 2) #(1 2))` or something. Right now it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, I think you want something like

```
split: lista by: anInteger
| groups j |

groups := OrderedCollection new.
j := 0.
lista withIndexDo: [:element :i | | group |
    i // anInteger = 0 
       ifTrue: [ group := Array new: anInteger. 
                 j := 1 ].
    group at: j put: element.
    j := j + 1.
    (j > anInteger or: [ i = lista size ]) 
       ifTrue: [groups add: group]. ].
^ groups
```